# Selecting more than one row using mysql

Tags: mysql

MySql table

```
CREATE TABLE cities (city VARCHAR(30)); 
  INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('St. Louis');
  INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('San Diego');
  INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Seattle');
```

MySql Query

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(30);
   SELECT @name = city FROM cities where name ='Seattle' limit 1;
```

By using the above query, I am able to select city name into @name variable. But when I am able to select multiple values:

MySQL Query

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(30);
   SELECT @name = city FROM cities;
```

We are getting exception as below:

```
Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row
```

How to select multiple values using select into command. Thanks

Comment: You can't put multiple scalar values in a single variable like that. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @GMB: I want to get multiple values into a variable, so that I can use the same variables to update some other table.

Comment: Please show us the entire use case then (typically, the update you want to run). You probably don't need a variable for that purpose.

Comment: It sounds like you want a JOIN. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can't select multiple values in a single string variable. If you are content with a CSV list of values, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
declare @names varchar(30);
select @names = group_concat(city) from cities;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use this @names in where condition for some other table (In operator)?

Comment: @Dylan: no. As commented under your question, you need to show us the actual use case, so we can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a temporary table and fill it with `SELECT` of another table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE name(city varchar(30)); 
INSERT INTO name SELECT cities FROM cities;
```